How can i get shopify product by using tag filter by using Admin REST api?
Hello i want to get shopify product by using admin REST api on my storefront theme. How can i apply tag filter to query?
When i am using GraphQl api it is not fetching the same product object as we have in liquid like.
Why I am doing this is I added a product id to different products and I want to fetch all products which have tag of that product id on the product detail page of that product but the response object shopuld be like same as we have product object in shopify liquid.
Right Now i am trying this solution because it fetches the same product objects like we have on shopify but the tag filter is not working.
fetch('https://mystore.myshopify.com/admin/api/2024-04/products.json?tag=summer-collection')

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2024-04/resources/product#get-products?ids=632910392,921728736 doesn't list tag as a valid parameter for that endpoint.
